# Erdos conjecture, number of cliques, Turan`s graph

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory, co.combinatorics, clique

Erdos&Stone conjectured in [1946-08](http://www.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1946-08.pdf) that

there are at least $ck-1$ (k+1)-cliques in $G=(V,E)$ 
whenever $|V|=ck$, $|E|-1$ is the edge-count in Turan's 
$T(|V|,k)$, i.e.,

$|E|= 1+\lfloor {(k-1)|V|^2} / (2k) \rfloor$.

I am looking to see whether this conjecture has been proved in literature. 
Didn't see a trace of it myself.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Isn't the conjecture in the paper that the number of $(k+1)$-cliques in this case is at least $c^{k-1}$? That's the number you get by adding a single edge to the Turan-graph. I think it's proved in [1969-10](http://www.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1969-10.pdf). Also relevant: [1983-28](http://www.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1983-28.pdf).
Recently, there has been significant progress on bounding the number of cliques as a function of the quadratic term of the number of edges: [arxiv:1212.2454](http://arxiv.org/abs/1212.2454).